# How to track retweets and facebook comments?

Tags: ios, facebook, api, twitter, oauth

i am trying to figure the best way to go about getting the number of retweets for a given tweet and likewise the number of comments for a specific facebook post.

I know there are api calls to retrieve these things individually using their respective apis however my question is how to achieve this on different platforms.

For example lets say i have both a web app and iOS app that i would like my users to be able to share images from to either facebook or twitter. I have used something like ShareKit on iOS to share the images and i could probably tweak it to capture the id for the tweet/post which i could then send back to the web app to store in  a db.

Question is then how do i go about getting the number of retweets/likes for these tweets and posts? Issue being that is that as far as i understand these are authenticated calls and i wouldnt have the proper authentication to get that info from facebook/twitter as the user would only have authorized my iOS app and not the web app? Is there a way for me to pass on the user authentication to my server from the iOS and then use that when making the calls to get the number of retweets/likes?

Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

You do **not** need to be authenticated to see how many retweets a tweet has.

The [documentation on showing tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) makes that very clear.

Let's say that the tweet ID is 211912719195058176

You can make this call to Twitter's API

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=211912719195058176&include_entities=true
```

In the response, you will see

```
"retweet_count":26
```

It's that simple.

Comment: Thx, i saw that the twitter mentioned that auth was optional however i believe for the FB api it is mandatory